# References not available when given a .sln file

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Why is it that whenever someone gives me a .sln files with several projects, that some references are not available? Shouldn't the DLL files be located somewhere inside a subfolder in the solution? Or are these references to assemblies in the GAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be any of the following reasons:

- They are referencing `NuGet Packages` which by default you don't need to send as you can do a `NuGet Package Restore`. See [NuGet Package Restore](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore). *Note: Update your NuGet Package Manager in Tools -> Extensions and Updates*
- They are referencing Assemblies which are in their GAC, therefore they are not being copied across.
- They are referencing assemblies from another location outside of the Solution root folder, therefore not being available at your end.
- They are not giving you the folder which contains the assemblies.

If you mention some assemblies which are missing, we may be able to help identify the reason.

Comment: Telerik.Web.UI and DocumentFormat.OpenXML are the dlls that are broken.

Comment: Usually Telerik assemblies are GAC'ed once you install the tools. And when you reference them inside your projects they do not live anywhere in the solution folder. The reason for this is because you are not allowed to distribute the Telerik assemblies to other developers, only the end users.